# after install of package, when does the package become visible?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In the conda environment, after using conda to install a package, at what point does that package become visible to code in the editor?

Comment: what do you mean by visible? you can import after installing

Comment: you can use pip show module_name to check its location. Do you mean to code or modify the module itself?